# Interval of convergent of $\sum_n \frac{x^{2^{n}}}{\left( 1-x\right) ^{2^{n+1}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

$$ \sum_n \frac{x^{2^{n}}}{\left( 1-x\right) ^{2^{n+1}}} $$

I think I got the answer but I'm not sure. Anyone who verify my answer?
$R=1$ and $x\in \left(0, 2\right) \backslash \left\{ 1\right\}$

Comment: This is not a power series, and so, the concept of radius of convergence and interval of convergence does not apply (at least directly). We may still discuss the set of $x$'s for which the series converges, but this is no longer guaranteed to be an interval centered at a point, and so, you have to examine the series manually.

Comment: You said that, it isn't a power series. Then, what we call them? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't have a particular name at all. This is just a series whose convergence (and value) depends on the choice of $x$. Of course, this series can be expanded into a power series about $x=0$, which begins with: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^n}}{(1-x)^{2^{n+1}}}=x + 3 x^2 + 7 x^3 + 15 x^4 + 33 x^5 + 77 x^6 + 183 x^7 + 423 x^8 + 937 x^9 + \cdots. $$ However, this rarely helps solve the original question, since the right-hand side converges only on a range which is much smaller than the range of convergence for the original series.

Comment: Okay, I understood. However, $\sum \dfrac{x^{n}}{n!}$ this is a power series, isn't it? If it's a power series then, I will have a big problem. Because, I can't see any difference between them.

Comment: A power series is very easy to tell. It can be regarded as an "infinite-degree polynomial". Indeed, a power series about the center $x=a$ is precisely of the form $$C_0 + C_1(x-a) + C_2(x-a)^2 + \cdots + C_n (x-a)^n + \cdots. $$ Any series that is not of this form for some $a$ and $C_n$'s is not a power series. In your case, note that each summand $x^{2^n}/(1-x)^{2^{n+1}}$ is not a polynomial at all! So it does not qualify as a power series. And this is not just for the definition's sake, since power series enjoy very nice properties that other kinds of series often do not.

Comment: Oh, I see very clearly. Thank you so much. Best regards.

Comment: @SangchulLee How did you get the expansion?

Comment: When I saw that expansion I thought it just Maclaurin, but I don't know if I'm wrong

Comment: @Raffaele, It can be obtained by using the formula $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{m}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{m-1+k}{k}x^k.$$ Then \begin{align*}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^n}}{(1-x)^{2^{n+1}}}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{2^{n+1}-1+k}{k}x^{2^n+k}\\&=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\Biggl(\sum_{\substack{n,k \geq 0\\2^n+k=l}}\binom{2^{n+1}-1+k}{k}\Biggr)x^l\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is not correct. For  $|\frac x {(1-x)^{2}}| <1$ so the series is convergent.  $|\frac x {(1-x)^{2}}| \geq 1$ it is divergent. Hence the region of convergence is $\mathbb R \setminus [\frac {3-\sqrt 5} 2, \frac {3+\sqrt 5} 2]$.  Radius of convergence is not defined for this series.

Comment: In my first solution, I found $\left( -\infty ,\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ but I wasn't sure so I erased it.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you pointing out. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @beingmathematician There was an error in the answer as pointed out by Sangchul Lee. I have edited the answer.